# WebClient - Pull 'DOM Snapshot Data' vs 'Source'

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-4.0, webclient

I'm trying to pull the DOM Snapshot Data (equivalent to doing an Inspect Element in Chrome) using C#. Here is my code:

```
string url = "http://someurl";
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.Load(new WebClient().OpenRead(url));
this.html = htmlDoc;
```

The issue is that it is just pulling the source, not the DOM snapshot. How can I pull the DOM snapshot in C#?

Comment: What is a DOM snapshot?  Do you mean you need scripts to run on the page and *then* get the HTML?  That's a much more complex process, meaning you have to run a JavaScript interpreter, etc.

Comment: Not possible without a complete headless web browser, none exists in complete form entirely in .NET that I know of. The "snapshot" is the DOM after scripts have run, and is dynamic. The easiest thing is to use a web browser control (e.g. Internet Explorer) though it's not fast or clean. Google ".NET headless web browser" for various discussions on the matter.